# paste causes duplicate pasting natively but not in other apps or remotely

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tkinter, debian, clipboard

When I use copy and paste in my little barebones text editor, I get a double paste. So, if I copy "test" what gets pasted is "testest". If I then try to copy "bla" what gets pasted is "testtestblabla." But if I cut something then only the material left over from the previous copy gets included in the paste--the cut material itself doesn't duplicate.

I've tried pasting text into Notepad and Wordpad, as well as online, and this phenomenon doesn't occur. But it does occur in both my Windows environment and my (dual-booted) Debian environment. The problem is identical in uncompiled scripts and standalone binaries compiled with pyinstaller in both Windows and Debian (and, incidentally, the latter otherwise executes without problems in both Linux and Windows, with the same problem).

Here's the offending code as far as I can tell:

```
def copy(self, event=None):
    text = self.editing_window.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
    self.display.clipboard_clear()
    self.display.clipboard_append(text)

def cut(self, event):
    self.copy()
    self.editing_window.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")

def paste(self, event):
    self.editing_window.insert(INSERT, self.display.clipboard_get())
```

Hardware: Dell Precision T1600, i3-3120, Quadro 600
OSS: Windows 7 and Debian 8.4

**There are no error messages even if console is open.** This could well be some sort of semantic problem.

Any solutions?

Comment: Please show a complete example. Most likely it's because you are implementing your own bindings, but tkinter already has bindings for cut, copy and paste.  Without seeing a full working example (of _just_ enough code to illustrate) it's hard to say for sure. see http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If tkinter does have its own bindings for cut, copy and paste, I'd love to use them instead, but you know what the state of tkinter documentation is, so I haven't been able to find out about them. Thanks for (perhaps unintentionally) providing me the tiny bit of help involved in informing me that those bindings exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on help I got here, I found some documentation (a 2010 Usenet post [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2010-December/002600.html)) that solves the problem by simply disabling my wrapper. Funny, but those builtins weren't working before I implemented the wrapper, and now they do. Thanks, all.